# Best Practices for Organizing Java Classes in a Spring Application using JPA for CRUD Operations?

Tags: java, spring, crud

We are currently developing a Java application utilizing CRUD methods with JPA within the Spring framework. Our codebase comprises various classes, including entity classes representing database tables, repositories, support classes for our hub classes, and views classes, all organized under the 'hc' main folder. How should one ideally organize and structure this many different interface classes and views within a Java application? What are the best practices for sorting or structuring classes like these in a Spring-based project using JPA for database operations?
[image: image of current structure]